# suppress gmock warning for a vector of mock class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am writting unit tests with gmock. I have some uninteresting function calls in my test body for which I would like to suppress the gmock warnings. However, I have tried several ways like NiceMock or EXPECT_CALL, but none of them are working. Here are something I have tried:

```
class MockClass : public OriginClass {
    // class body
    int aFunc();
}

NiceMock<std::vector<MockClass> > mock_vector;

NiceMock<MockClass> tmp;
mock_vector.push_back(tmp);

EXPECT_CALL(tmp, aFunc())
    .WillRepeatedly(Return(1));
```

But I keep get gmock warning of uninteresting function call. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so finally I found the answer myself.

The problem is that gmock doesn't provide a move constructor for NiceMock. so we have to change the vector of class to a vector of unique_ptr, and the problem is solved.

concretely, it should be like this:

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NiceMock<MockClass>>> my_mockclass;`

when pushing new elements back, you should use:

`my_mockclass.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NiceMock<MockClass>>());`

It should solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Gmock wanrings can also be very easily suppressed by adding `--gmock_verbose=error` to the command line.

http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#controlling-how-much-information-gmock-prints